# FSCK check in the Solaris System

Tags: unix

When we booted our Solaris server, the `/opt` file system was unmounted 
with the error:

```
/dev/vx/rdsk/bootdg/opt: PARTIALLY TRUNCATED INODE I=225
/dev/vx/rdsk/bootdg/opt: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.

THE FOLLOWING FILE SYSTEM(S) HAD AN UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY: /dev/vx/rdsk/bootdg/opt (/opt)
fsckall failed with exit code 1.

WARNING - Unable to repair one or more filesystems.
Run fsck manually (fsck filesystem...).

mount: Please run fsck and try again
svc:/system/filesystem/local:default: WARNING: /sbin/mountall -l failed: exit status 32
```

This is the command we have fired:

```
fsck /dev/vx/rdsk/bootdg/opt

** /dev/vx/rdsk/bootdg/opt
** Last Mounted on /opt
** Phase 1 - Check Blocks and Sizes
PARTIALLY TRUNCATED INODE I=225
SALVAGE?
```

So the main problem that we are facing here is that we are giving 'Yes' for all the answers.  If we give 'No', then it gets terminated.  It's very tough for us to give 'Yes' always.

So, we need your kind and expert help on this:

1. Is that we can include any option in the fsck.
2. What is the way forward to make the opt file system to get mounted.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can supply the option `-y` to `fsck`:

   ```
   fsck -y /dev/vx/rdsk/bootdg/opt
   ```

   This automatically supplies 'yes' to every question.  In my experience, if `fsck` suggests a way to fix something, then (a) it is right, and (b) you have to know more about the way your specific file system works than `fsck` does to have a chance of doing anything useful if you say 'No' to anything.

   There is a companion option `-n` to answer No to every question.
2. Run the `fsck` command with `-y`.  You do have a backup, don't you?  So if a file really is missing, you can recover from it?  Oh, that's sad...well, make sure you have a backup before it happens next time.

Basically, unless you're enough of a file system guru not to need to ask this question in the first place, you need to answer 'yes' to all the questions `fsck` asks you.  Doing that automatically is most sensible, hence the `-y` option.

The other alternative is to simply reformat the entire (`/opt`) file system; that also usually works.